# Why does my th:each not work in my div? Thymleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, backend

I'm trying to th:text in my div but it doesnt seem to work

I tried doing it with a table and i get the data i need but when i put it in a div it doesnt work

```
     <div class="info"  data-th-each="shoes: ${shoesList}">
          <p th:text="$(shoes.name)"></p>
          <p th:text="$(shoes.description)"></p>
          <p th:text="$(shoes.price)"></p>          
      </div>
```

This works tho

```
<table>

      <tr data-th-each="shoes : ${shoesList}">    
        <td th:text="${shoes.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${shoes.description}"></td>
        <td th:text="${shoes.price}"></td>
      </tr>        
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think, it will be following way
( correct $(shoes.name) to ${shoes.name} )**

```
<div class="info"  th:each="shoes : ${shoesList}">
      <p th:text="${shoes.name}"></p>
      <p th:text="${shoes.description}"></p>
      <p th:text="${shoes.price}"></p>          
  </div>
```

Please visit this link
[Iteration thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-iteration)